# Calculate Usage time per day and customer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a Pandas DataFrame with monthly events send by customers, like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
[
    ('2017-01-01 12:00:00', 'SID1', 'Something', 'A. Inc'),
    ('2017-01-02 00:30:00', 'SID1', 'Something', 'A. Inc'),
    ('2017-01-02 12:00:00', 'SID2', 'Something', 'A. Inc'),
    ('2017-01-01 15:00:00', 'SID4', 'Something', 'B. GmbH')
],
    columns=['TimeStamp', 'Session ID', 'Event', 'Customer']
)
```

The Session IDs are unique, but could spann multiple days. In addition multiple sessions could occur on a given day.

I would like to calculate the minutes of usage for each day of the months per customer like this.

| Customer | 01.01 | 02.01 | ... | 31.01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A. Inc | 720 | 30 | ... | 50 |
| B. GmbH | 1 | 0 | ... | 0 |

I suspect, that a split of Timestamp into Days and Time, followed by groupby('Customer', 'Day', 'Session ID') and then applying (via apply()) some maths is the way to go, but so far i could not produce any real progress.

Comment: Your data set is missing something like a "Session duration" column. It doesn't seem possible to calculate the minutes of usage right now. You will most likely need to do a `.groupby(...).sum(...)` anyway

Comment: Agree with @edd313.  Duration or end-time is needed for each session.

Comment: or perhaps some event code which signifies a timestamp is the start of a session, or end of a session

Comment: Thank you all for the Input! Sadly, due to incomplete Data, sometimes no session end event is recorded, but i can use the last recorded event as session end.
`group_Session = df.groupby(['Session ID'])`
`df['Session Time'] = group_Session['TimeStamp'].transform(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution, might not be the best, but works.

```
# group by id and add max and min values of each group to new columns
group_Session = df.groupby(['Session ID']) 
df['Start Time'] = group_Session['Timestamp'].transform(lambda x: x.min())
df['Stop Time'] = group_Session['Timestamp'].transform(lambda x: x.max())
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Session ID'], keep='first', inplace = True)
# now we have start/stop for each session
# add all days of month to dataframe and fill with zeros
dateStart = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 1)
dateStop = (dateStart + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(day = 31))
for single_date in (dateStart.day + n for n in range(dateStop.day)):
    df[str(single_date) + '.' + str(dateStart.month)] = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    # Create a dateRange from start to finisch with minute frequency
    # Convert dateRange to Dataframe
    dateRangeFrame = pd.date_range(start = row['Start Time'], end = row['Stop Time'], freq = 'T').to_frame(name = 'value')
    # extract day from dateIndex
    dateRangeFrame['day'] = dateRangeFrame['value'].dt.strftime('%#d.%#m')
    #group by day and count the results -> now we have: per session(index) a day/minute object  
    day_to_minute_df = dateRangeFrame.groupby(['day']).count()
    # for each group find column from index and add sum of val
    for d2m_index, row in day_to_minute_df.iterrows():
        df.loc[index, d2m_index] = row['value']
new_df = df.groupby(['Customer']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
Extract date and time in minutes to new colums. Then sum time for customer and date using groupby and agg. Then finally pivot the dataframe.

```
df['TimeStamp']= df['TimeStamp'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df['date'] = df['TimeStamp'].dt.date
df['minutes'] = df['TimeStamp'].dt.strftime('%H:%M').apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]) * 60 + int(x.split(':')[1]))

new_df = df.groupby(['Customer','date']).agg({'minutes': sum}).reset_index()
print(pd.pivot_table(new_df, values = 'minutes', index=['Customer'], columns = 'date'))
```

**Output:**

```
date      2017-01-01  2017-01-02
Customer                        
A. Inc         720.0       750.0
B. GmbH        900.0         NaN
```